# convert imported matrix to dist object

Tags: r, matrix, distance

I have a precomputed distance matrix that I would like to import to R. In order to do so i am using the following:

`host.dists <- data.matrix(read.table("host.txt", fill=T, row.names=1, skip=1, col.names=1:73))`

that imports the matrix which looks like this: (see attached picture)
[imported data matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05BZJ.jpg)

however what I want is to convert this matrix to a 'dist' object and I havent managed to do that so far...

I have tried using the `as.dist(host.dists)` but it returns the same object

any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks
P

Comment: Please provide reproducible example. This works for me: `D <- dist(1:10)` `E <- as.matrix(D)` `F <- as.dist(E)` `str(F)` outputs `Class 'dist'...`

Comment: Which is the output of `class(host.dists)`. If it is a `matrix` just give it `dist`format with the following code: `host.dists <- dist(host.dists)`

Comment: Thanks Chi Pak 'E <- as.matrix(host.dists)' and 
'host.dists <- as.dist(E)' did the trick just fine!

Comment: Thanks R18 as well!

Comment: it was matrix R18, but for some reason as.dist wasnt working directly :-o